# Make a MATLAB plot disappear behind a 2D Gaussian of single color with varying values of transparency

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The `MATLAB` code below draws a 2D green Gaussian with varaying values of transparancy, which represent a wave function.

The code also draws a red plot, which represents a laser pulse. (See the attached figure).

I want to have the red laser pulse be plotted in the background, so that the part of it which crosses the 2D Gaussian will be invisible.

Is there some kind of a way to achieve this ??

[image: The figure produced:]

```
function forQ
    close all; clc
    figure
    xlim_min=-11;
    xlim_max=11;
    ylim_min=-11;
    ylim_max=11; 
    global size_of_wavefunction;  size_of_wavefunction=2.5;        
    global x_laser; x_laser=-10.5:0.01:10.5;
    global omega; omega=8;
    global laser_strength; laser_strength=10;

    draw_main_wave_function;    
    hold on       
    laser_x_offset=-1.2;
    hold on
    drawLaser(laser_x_offset);
    hold on
    draw_main_wave_function;            
    ylim([ylim_min ylim_max])
    xlim([xlim_min xlim_max])    
    axis square
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function drawLaser(x_offset)    
    global x_laser;    
    global omega;
    global laser_strength;        
    envelope_extinction=3;        
    y_laser=laser_strength*exp(-envelope_extinction*(x_laser/10).^2).*cos(omega*(x_laser/10));    
    y_laser_for_plot=-y_laser;
    x_laser_for_plot=x_laser+x_offset;    
    plot(x_laser_for_plot,y_laser_for_plot,'-r','LineWidth',3)        
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function draw_main_wave_function

    global size_of_wavefunction;

    pre_exp_factor=0.5*0.8;
    c1=size_of_wavefunction*0.3;
    in_exp_factor=c1;
    x_offset=0;
    y_offset=0;

    draw_wave_function(pre_exp_factor, in_exp_factor, x_offset, y_offset);
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function draw_wave_function( pre_exp_factor,in_exp_factor,...
                             x_offset, y_offset )  

    x=-3:0.01:3;  
    y=-3:0.01:3;  
    if (y_offset~=0)
        x=-5:0.1:5;  
        y=-11:0.1:11;         
    end
    [X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);


    w_function=pre_exp_factor*exp(-in_exp_factor*((X-x_offset).^2+...
                                      (Y-y_offset).^2));

    colorMap = [0 , 1, 0];
    colormap(colorMap);

    min_alpha = 0; % desired minimum alpha
    max_alpha = 1; % desired maximum alpha
    alpha = min_alpha + (max_alpha-min_alpha)/max(w_function(:))*w_function; % compute alpha
    imagesc(x,y,w_function,'AlphaData',alpha,'AlphaDataMapping','none'); % image with alpha

end
```

Comment: provide a minimal example , bla bla bla...

Answer (score 0):

Use 3D plots with `plot3` and manually set the placement of objects.

`view(2)` set the 3D figure view to the xy-plot (it might not be necessary in your code).

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
figure
hold all
y = x(32);
plot3(y,sin(y),0*y+1,'go','MarkerSize',22,'MarkerFaceColor','g')
plot3(x,sin(x),0*x,'r-','LineWidth',3)
view(2)
```